# DNS troubleshooting and Bind Error

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

When we access carsizler.com by domain name it takes too much time, but when we access the site by IP (103.225.77.2) it opens very quickly without any delay. Can you help us determine what the problem could be?

We are using Bind9.

Answer (score 6):

Because you didn't redact the domain name (thank you!), this one is hopefully simple: you are advertising two IP addresses under that A record:

```
[madhatta@risby madhatta]$ dig carsizler.com
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
carsizler.com.          38400   IN      A       103.225.77.3
carsizler.com.          38400   IN      A       103.225.77.2
```

Most browsers will try one of those addresses at random, and it looks like the one that you don't list isn't running a web server:

```
[madhatta@risby madhatta]$ telnet 103.225.77.3 80
Trying 103.225.77.3...
telnet: connect to address 103.225.77.3: No route to host
```

Stop advertising the `.3` address and things should speed up.  Note that because your TTL is so large (38400s), it might be over ten hours before all affected clients see the fix.

Comment: I fix the error. It was due to firewall. Any way thanks a lot.